# How to add class when user reaches page bottom vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

I am struggling to find any kind of reference to this but what I want to achieve is toggle a class at page scroll bottom and remove it again when scrolling back up

I am not so familiar with JS and don't really know where to start - I don't want to use jQuery

```js
var footer = document.querySelector('.site-footer');


footer.classList.toggle('show');
```

```css
section {
  height:150vh;
}

.site-footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom:-100%;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background:red;
  transition: bottom 0.5s ease;
}

.site-footer.show {
  bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<section></section>
<div class="site-footer"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the window's `innerHeight` and `pageYOffset` together are equal to or greater than the page's `offsetHeight`:

```js
var footer = document.querySelector('.site-footer');
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  const atBottom = document.body.offsetHeight - (innerHeight + pageYOffset) <= 0;
  footer.classList.toggle('show', atBottom);
}, {
  passive: true
});
```

```css
section {
  height: 150vh;
}

.site-footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: -100%;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  transition: bottom 0.5s ease;
}

.site-footer.show {
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<section></section>
<div class="site-footer">footer</div>
```

Comment: A little shorter if you use `.toggle` with the second parameter. `footer.classList.toggle('show', atBottom);`

Comment: `.toggle` won't work since the scroll listener runs on every scroll action, not *only* when scolling reaches the bottom or goes back up.

Comment: Putting your boolean as the second argument to `.toggle()` gives it the same behavior you get with `[atBottom ? "add" : "remove"]`

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about that, that's pretty cool, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can add an event listener for the scroll event and toggle the 'show' class.

```js
var footer = document.querySelector('.site-footer');
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
  footer.classList.toggle('show', 
    this.innerHeight + this.scrollY >= document.scrollingElement.scrollHeight);
});
```

```css
section {
  height:150vh;
}

.site-footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom:-100%;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background:red;
  transition: bottom 0.5s ease;
}

.site-footer.show {
  bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<section></section>
<div class="site-footer"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your not handling super legacy browsers, use an [intersection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) observer.

You dont have to listen to scroll, ready, or whatever... Just listen to when the bounding reacts state changes and react to that.